# SQL Server - ignoring always true condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to add to the `WHERE` clause one condition, which is always true, but it must reference one of the columns, for example:

`ID` is the primary key (and therefore `NOT NULL`)

and I will execute a select:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table 
WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL
```

Will this condition be ignored or checked for every row?

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server can determine at compile time that this condition will always be true and avoid the need to check at runtime.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
X INT CONSTRAINT UQ_X UNIQUE
)

SELECT X 
FROM #T 
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;    

DROP TABLE #T
```

[image]

In the execution plan above the only index accessed is `UQ_X` and this doesn't even contain the `ID` column that would make such a runtime evaluation possible.

By contrast if `ID` is nullable (and replaced with a unique constraint rather than primary key as a PK wouldn't allow NULL) then the check would of course need to be made at run time and so the plan will need to retrieve the column and might look like one of the following.

### Scans whole table with predicate pushed into scan

[image]

### Attempt to use narrower index requires lookup to retrieve the column and evaluate the predicate

[image]

Comment: So I can use this condition and don't worry about performance? :)

Comment: @Mateusz - Probably. There might be some edge cases where it makes a difference though. Even [`1=1`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108784/3690) isn't always without effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;
```

It will display all the rows in your table given that ID is defined as the primary key. This will be similar to `SELECT * FROM Table;` from the display point of view. However, the condition will not be ignored.(i.e. the `where` clause will be checked)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        *
FROM          TableName
WHERE        (ID IS NOT NULL)
```

All the data where ID is not null will be displayed.
Id will not be null if `ID` is primary key in the table !
Hence you will get all the datas from the table